# Using StackService.Text and JSON for lists of objects

Tags: c#, json, servicestack, servicestack-text

Any help will be appreciated here.

I'm trying to use StackService. Text and **JSON** in order to get a list of objects, that each object contains a list.

Here is the definition of the classes:

```
[DataContract]
public class GroupingList
{
    [DataMember(Name = "id")]
    public int Id
    {
        get; set;
    }
    [DataMember(Name = "name")]
    public string Name
    {
        get; set;
    }
    [DataMember(Name = "form_field")]
    public string FormField
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    [DataMember(Name = "groups")]
    public List<GroupingOptions> Groups
    {
        get; set;
    }
}

[DataContract]
public class GroupingOptions
{
    [DataMember(Name = "bit")]
    public string Bit
    {
        get; set;
    }
    [DataMember(Name = "name")]
    public string Name
    {
        get; set;
    }
    [DataMember(Name = "display_order")]
    public string DisplayOrder
    {
        get; set;
    }
    [DataMember(Name = "subscribers")]
    public int Subscribers
    {
        get; set;
    }
}
```

I'm using the 'PostJsonToUrl()' method, and receiving the following string as a return result:

```
"\n[{\"id\":14101,\"name\":\"Accounting1\",\"form_field\":\"hidden\",\"display_order\":\"0\",\"groups\":[{\"bit\":\"1\",\"name\":\"Interest\",\"display_order\":\"1\",\"subscribers\":null},{\"bit\":\"2\",\"name\":\"Register\",\"display_order\":\"2\",\"subscribers\":null}]}]"
```

Now, when I'm trying to call the `FromJson(List<GroupingList>)` method, I'm getting the following exception:

```
Type definitions should start with a '{', expecting serialized type 'GroupingList', got string starting with: 
[{"id":14101,"name":"Accounting1","form_field":"h
```

Can anyone direct me please whether this issue is related to the definition of the 'GroupingList' and 'GroupingOptions' classes? The return result of 'PostJsonToUrl()' is a list (with one entry in this case) that contain another list (with two items), so I don't understand why calling FromJson(List) fails.

Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is `\n` symbol at the begining of the string. You can remove it first, and then desirialize `GroupingList`.

```
string result = "\n[{\"id\":14101,\"name\":\"Accounting1\",\"form_field\":\"hidden\",\"display_order\":\"0\",\"groups\":[{\"bit\":\"1\",\"name\":\"Interest\",\"display_order\":\"1\",\"subscribers\":0},{\"bit\":\"2\",\"name\":\"Register\",\"display_order\":\"2\",\"subscribers\":0}]}]";
result = result.Trim();
List<GroupingList> list = result.FromJson<List<GroupingList>>();
```

Comment: Hi Dmitry, I still have no idea why it's working. I had several strings begin with \n and I could deserialize them to other objects (not GroupingList). However, it did solve my problem, thank you very much for that!